# Regex extracting numbers & letters - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

And again, I am having issues with regex.
Well basically I want to extract info from a website, and get it in a textbox.
`<a href="/player/11111">what I want to be extracted</a>`
So as you can see, the part what says 11111 must be enabled to also extract letters instead of only numbers. 
I use this code:

```
Dim mcol As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "/player/\d+"">(.+)</a>")
```

How can I make it to extract not only numbers, but both.
So it will be enable to extract a MD5 hash?

Kind regards

Comment: Don't use RegEx to extract HTML, use an xml parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

`/\w+/i` it will match any alphanumeric character with case insensitive modifier. As we know that `MD5` is 32 digit hexadecimal number so the above regex may be useful in your case.

Comment: Mind making a short version? I got dislexia, and it's a pain in the ass to read it all.